# Multilingual site in Genesis framework

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, multilingual

I am trying to build a multilingual site in four languages.
I only want the front end to be multilingual and just use English for the Admin area.
Considering that I'm using Genesis framework, What plugin is the best and is compatible with Genesis?

Also is it possible to point 4 different domains to a single Wordpress site but each domain for a specific language?
So when you for example click on the French domain, it loads the French Site?

I really appreciate any opinion on this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.wpmayor.com/plugin-reviews/wpml-review/

compatible with Genesis? YES

each domain for a specific language? YES

Comment: Thank You for the reply.
I'm going to give it a try.